# Solving a simple ordinary differential equation and calculating second derivatives

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following ode:
$$
p' y' = -p y''
$$
and I want to see how $y$ depends on $p$ , and then see how $y''$ depends on $p$ .

Will you please help me verify my solution ? :

define: $q=y'$, and then the equation becomes:
$$
-\frac{p'}{p}=\frac{q'}{q}
$$
which has the solution $$ q= C \frac{1}{p}. $$
Hence:
$$
y=\int_0 ^x q \, ds =C \int_0 ^x  \frac{1}{p} \,ds +D
$$
where $C,D$ are integration constants.

As for the second derivative:
$$
y''= - C \cdot \frac{p' }{p^2}
$$

Is my solution correct?

Thanks a lot in advance !

Comment: your solution looks good.

Comment: can you post the original equation please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution looks alright except where you have $y'/y$ where you must have intended $q'/q$.

Here's another way to look at it:
$$
p'y' + py'' = 0 
$$
$$
(py')'=0 \tag{by the product rule}
$$
$$
py' = \text{constant}
$$
$$
y' = \frac{\text{constant}} p
$$
$$
y = \text{constant}\cdot\int \frac{ds} p
$$
so then there's the question of whether you can do something with that last integral.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Michael Hardy. My calculation of the second derivative is also correct?